# (parser related) removing \newcommand and \renewcommand without structural and contentual changes

Tags: macros, environments, latex-misc, tex-general

I am trying to remove all `\newcommand`s, `\renewcommand`s, `\newenvironment`s and `\newenvironment`s in Latex files without any structural and contentual changes.

As I understood the only purpose of these commands is to ease writing Latex and save time.

My Idea:

1. Replace a renewed command by a new command with a new name
2. Replace all the instances of the renewed command in the file with the new name
3. Replace all the instances of all new commands in the file with the corresponding definition

Is this possible without any changes related to the structure and content of file?

Comment: What on earth would be the point of such an exercise?

Comment: @AlanMunn  I have to build a parser for a subset of latex. Having these commands makes it more difficult.

Comment: Your method won't work if catcode changes are involved. You need to know also the context of the `\newcommand`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am aware of catcode. Could you please explain more or recommend some scources about the context of the \newcommand.

Comment: Related: [Is there a BNF grammar of the TeX language?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/4201) and [Generate a parse tree for TeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/21870)

Comment: @AlanMunn I have read both of them. I am not going to parse the whole Latex. I want to extract some parts of Latex like section and math and the rest will be handed over to "pdftotext".

Comment: "I have to build a parser for a subset of LaTeX" isn't quite an answer either. What are you trying to achieve with this parsing?  Your last comment seems to imply that you're converting to text in some way. But if that's your goal there are already converters that can do some of this stuff for you, e.g. `pandoc` and `tex4ht`.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of a command depends on the state of the catcode table at definition time.

This means that you can't simply copy the definition body and hope that it works.

As an example (I wrote it so that it doesn't give an error):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\somecommand
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{4}
   {\int x}
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$
 \somecommand
$ 

\bigskip

$ %body of \somecommand
 \int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{4}
    {\int x}
$   


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if we do not allow to change the catcode table? Is the replacement then possible? Or are there other problems?

Comment: You could make the same point even simpler without `expl3` with `\makeatletter\newcommand\mycommand{\@ne}\makeatother`.

Comment: David showed another problem. And you didn't speak about (mandatory and optional) arguments yet ...

Comment: @AlanMunn I know. But I found it neat to get an `\int`. Also the use of expl3  is something that one should expect, at least if egreg is around ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Your substitution rules need to be a lot more complicated than you describe.

Consider the common idiom for controlling a list of items

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\zz{\elt a\elt b\elt c\elt d}
\newcommand\elt{\renewcommand\elt{, }}

\begin{document}

\zz

\end{document}
```

This typesets as

> a, b, c, d

Now of course there are other ways of typesetting a list without putting the separator (`,` here) in front of the first item, but this method crucially depends on `\elt` being redefined, so you would have to globally analyse the use and change it to expand the `\elt` in different ways depending on where they are used.